# Is It Possible to set cpu affinity for particular user?

Tags: linux, redhat, central-processing-unit

I mean is their any way we can set up cpu affinity for particular user, for all his currently running process or for process which he will start later?

Comment: Which version of Red Hat is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

I would execute the user's processes into a [cgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) comprised of the CPU core(s) you wish to use. Depending on your version of RHEL (5 versus 6), you could use CPU shields via [cpusets/cset](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_management_utility/tutorial) in EL5 or try the [cgroup approach](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-Moving_a_Process_to_a_Control_Group.html) documented in EL6. The latter example uses an `/etc/cgrules.conf` file which defines rules for cgroup resources (e.g. all of the processes belonging to *Jerome* will run in a specified cgroup). The former allows you to execute processes directly into a CPU shield.

For your example using `cset`, I would simply execute a bash shell for the user into the right CPU shield. All of their child proceses will be contained within. See [here](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_management_utility/tutorial#Moving_Interesting_Tasks_Into_and_Out_of_the_Shield).

Answer (score 1):

The following small bash-script will do it:

```
u=username # do not set this to root!
c=logical processor number you want to bind to
for p in $(pgrep -u $u)
  do
    taskset -cp $c $p
done
```

Children of the bound processes will stay bound to that cpu-set.